# How to initialize sound in VirtualBox's VRDP?

Tags: rdp, virtualbox, gentoo

On my Gentoo Linux host, running VirtualBox 1.6.28, I'm unable to negotiate a VRDP (RDP-4 version) connection because the rdesktop-vrdp client fails to initialize sound so it doesn't connect at all as a consequence, even if the VM has no sound enabled *and* a parameter is passed to the rdesktop client to disable it!

```
hatsumemio@mintpc:~$ rdesktop-vrdp -4 -a 16 -N localhost:3394  -r sound:off
Autoselected keyboard map en-gb
ERROR: channel_register
WARNING: Initializing sound-support failed!
ERROR: Connection closed
```

My VRDE settings

```
VRDE:                        
enabled (Address 127.0.0.1, Ports 3394, MultiConn: off,    ReuseSingleConn: off,       Authentication type: null)
VRDE port:                   3394
Video redirection:           enabled (Quality 80)
VRDE property               : TCP/Ports  = "3394"
VRDE property               : TCP/Address = "127.0.0.1"
VRDE property               : VideoChannel/Enabled = "1"
VRDE property               : VideoChannel/Quality = "80"
VRDE property               : VideoChannel/DownscaleProtection = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableDisplay = "0"
VRDE property               : Client/DisableInput = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableAudio = "1"
VRDE property               : Client/DisableUSB = "0"
VRDE property               : Client/DisableClipboard = "0"
VRDE property               : Client/DisableUpstreamAudio = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableRDPDR = <not set>
VRDE property               : H3DRedirect/Enabled = <not set>
VRDE property               : Security/Method = <not set>
VRDE property               : Security/ServerCertificate = <not set>
VRDE property               : Security/ServerPrivateKey = <not set>
VRDE property               : Security/CACertificate = <not set>
VRDE property               : Audio/RateCorrectionMode = "VRDP_AUDIO_MODE_LPF"
VRDE property               : Audio/LogPath = <not set>
```

Sound settings

```
Audio:                       disabled
Audio playback:              disabled
Audio capture:               disabled
```

The "Remote Desktops" chapter of VirtualBox's official manual has no mention of how to get sound to work. Therefore, my question is this: How can I initialize sound in order to the client to connect without falling back to plain RDP?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is actually related to the sound not being able to initialize? That the error message follows the warning doesn't necessarily mean that there is a connection between the two.

Comment: Hmmm, good point, I assumed that it was the sound because I saw no other error. Looking closer, the channel_register is an error while the sound a warning. I wish there was more information than this. `channel_register` looks like some kind of internal object, though. It's also weird how it connects if I don't specify an RDP version, but then nothing more than basic display works.